# A simple C++ While loop not working

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a simple while loop i'm trying to implement but for the life of me can't figure out what I'm missing. I have currentuser initialized at the top to -1

```
while(currentuser = -1){
    cout << "Enter user ID: ";
    cin >> id;
    currentuser = search(a, length, id);
}
```

My search function is this:

```
int search (User a[ ], int length, string userID){
    User u;
    string tempid;
    int templegnth; //I ignore length for now as I will use it later
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
        tempid = a[i].getID();
        templegnth = tempid.length();
        if((tempid == userID)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;


}
```

I know its something very simple but the answer escapes me right now.

Comment: change it to `while(currentuser == -1)` Note `==`. If that's not it, you might consider actually describing what the problem is and asking a question.

Comment: Which chapter of your book clearly differentiates between the = operator and the == operator? Hmmm...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `=` (assignment) operator is not the same as the `==` (equality) operator.

The line :

```
while(currentuser = -1){
```

first assigns `-1` to `currentuser`, and then checks if `currentuser` has a non-zero value. This will always be the case (`-1 != 0`), so the loop will never end.

You likely meant this instead :

```
while(currentuser == -1){
```

which compares `currentuser` to `-1`, and continues the loop as long as that comparison is true.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change:

```
while(currentuser = -1){
```

to be:

```
while(currentuser == -1){
```

Currently you are assigning `currentuser` to `-1` every time your loop runs, rather than checking if it is still assigned to that value.

Answer (score 4):

Try `== -1` instead of `= -1`

Answer (score 3):

You've got the answers but here is a tip on how to avoid it in the future.
Always try to use

```
while(-1 == currentuser){
  std::cout << "Enter user ID: ";
  std::cin >> id;
  currentuser = search(a, length, id);
}
```

as this way

```
while(-1 = currentuser){
  ;
}
```

will be thrown out by the compiler

Comment: I would argue that the loss in readability may not be offset by the extra syntax checking.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the = changed to ==, the loop still has problems.

```
while(currentuser == -1){
  std::cout << "Enter user ID: ";
  std::cin >> id;
  currentuser = search(a, length, id);
}
```

Typing an EOT (control-D on a Linux box, control-Z? on windows) will raise `std::cin`'s end of file condition. The value of `id` won't be changed, and the lookup will presumably keep on returning -1. The result is an infinite loop with lots of spew to `std::cout`.

One way to fix this is to `break` out of the loop when the `std::cin >> id;` fails. For example, `if (! (std::cin >> id)) break;`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use a while loop and a boolean, I try to make sure it only runs if it is above or is 50 but instead whenever I execute a cout with the while and int, the outcome is a literal mess, its like the while loop executes a lot more than it should. Eg.

```
int Buses;
int People;
cin >> People;
while(People >= 50){
Buses += 1;
People -= 50;
};
cout << Buses << endl;
```

and when I input 757, my result was 32782.

Even by subtracting the int value by 32767, the values sort of fix itself but not the higher numbers, 99 is 1, 101 is 2 but c++ says that 300 is 3 although it is meant to be 6.

(My solution I found: I had to declare the Person and Buses variable with a 0 because the value was different without the starting 0.)

This is the fixed code:

```
int Buses = 0;
int People = 0;
cin >> People;
while(People >= 50){
Buses += 1;
People -= 50;
};
cout << Buses << endl;
```